# Capistrano deployment issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, rvm, capistrano

I've been wrestling with Capistrano, trying to deploy a test rails app for a couple of days, and I *think* I'm almost there, but I'm getting this error when I run `cap deploy`:

```
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd var/rails/test_app/current/releases/20120619215252 && bundle install --gemfile var/rails/test_app/current/releases/20120619215252/Gemfile --path var/rails/test_app/current/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on my.vps.ip.address
```

What does it mean and how can I resolve the issue?

Thanks!

This is my deploy.rb file, if it helps:

```
# RVM

$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'default'
set :rvm_type, :system

# Bundler

require "bundler/capistrano"

# General

set :application, "test_app"
set :user, "rails"

set :deploy_to, "var/rails/test_app/current"
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :use_sudo, false

# Git

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "~/Projects/test_app/.git"
set :branch, "master"

# VPS

role :web, "my.vps.ip.address"
role :app, "my.vps.ip.address"
role :db,  "my.vps.ip.address", :primary => true
role :db,  "my.vps.ip.address"

# Passenger

namespace :deploy do
 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

Comment: not related to your problem, RVM since 1.11.3 has extracted rvm/capistrano to a gem and the first line is no more required ... but you should get a warning about that - just read the outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano is trying to go in the latest deployment folder and run "bundle install".
The problem seems to be the folder where capistrano tries to do this :
You are doing `cd var/rails/test_app/current/releases/20120619215252 && bundle install ...`
A / is missing at the start of the path, that should be /var/rails...
You should have made a mistake overriding the path somewhere in the recipe.

Seeing your recipe you should have ( watch for the / )

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/rails/test_app/"
```

Don't specify the "current" folder, this is a capistrano default behavior.
Be sure that /var/rails/test_app/ is owned by the user used for deployment. Else : `chown -R rails:rails /var/rails/test_app/`
rails:rails, because you `set :user, "rails"` in your recipe.

Also don't forget to `cap deploy:setup` to build the directory structure...

Comment: @Julien_P. I just tried `/var/`, but I don't think that's the problem, as I get this error a lot earlier on than previously: `"rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd /var/rails/test_app/current/releases && tar xzf /tmp/20120619221837.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20120619221837.tar.gz'"'`

Comment: Anyway `var/` is not correct, And I'm not sure that you can `deploy_via copy` straight from a git repository.

Comment: Moreover, /var/rails/test_app/current/releases does not exists on your server, remove the "current" part of the deploy folder destination.